# How to locate mongoDB "bin" directory in CentOS?

Tags: centos, mongodb

I have installed mongoDB in my centOS server by using the below command:

1) Create a /etc/yum.repos.d/mongodb-org-3.4.repo file and insert:

```
[mongodb-org-3.4]
name=MongoDB Repository
baseurl=https://repo.mongodb.org/yum/redhat/$releasever/mongodb-org/3.4/x86_64/
gpgcheck=1
enabled=1
gpgkey=https://www.mongodb.org/static/pgp/server-3.4.asc
```

2) sudo yum install -y mongodb-org

When I type mongo -version, I get 
**MongoDB shell version v3.4.6**

But I coudn't locate the bin directory in my machine. Where is the default directory of mongodb located on linux and how to find it? Any help is appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 4):

You can use `which mongo` to get the path to the binary. 
From the man: `which - shows the full path of (shell) commands.`

Another option is to check where the RPM was installed to
`rpm -ql mongo` and for additional info of the RPM `rpm -qi mongo`

To get the name of the package, in case its not mongo, use `rpm -qa | grep mongo` to look for RPMs containing the name mongo

Comment: Thanks for your reply. When I use which mongo command, I get 
/usr/bin/mongo. This is a binary file.There is no folder inside of /usr/bin/mongo. I would like to find out where the bin folder is located. (mongo/bin)

Comment: I added another option using `rpm`. Hope this is what you were looking for